# Mysql/Tomcat/MobileFirst Openjpa error no persistance metadata

Tags: mysql, ibm-mobilefirst, openjpa, mobilefirst-server, worklight-server

Trying to upgrade worklight 6.1 to mobilefirst 7.1 through Ibm installer and configuration tool. Tomcat server 7.0.30 starts but I never have runtimes in my console. The server log produces this error.

```
     appcenterdb-mysql  INFO   [localhost-startStop-1] openjpa.Runtime - Starting OpenJPA 1.2.2
0  appcenterdb-mysql  INFO   [localhost-startStop-1] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Using dictionary class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.MySQLDictionary" (MySQL 5.6.19 ,MySQL Connector Java mysql-connector-java-5.1.25 ( Revision: ${bzr.revision-id} )).
<openjpa-1.2.2-r422266:898935 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Type "class com.ibm.puremeap.jpa.entity.OneTimeUrlEntity" does not have persistence metadata.
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingTool.getMapping(MappingTool.java:682)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingTool.buildSchema(MappingTool.java:748)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingTool.run(MappingTool.java:646)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCBrokerFactory.synchronizeMappings(JDBCBrokerFactory.java:153)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCBrokerFactory.newBrokerImpl(JDBCBrokerFactory.java:119)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.newBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:189)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBrokerFactory.newBroker(DelegatingBrokerFactory.java:142)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:192)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:145)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at com.ibm.puremeap.resources.data.impl.PrincipalHelper.createAndMakeSpecialPrincipalUnique(PrincipalHelper.java:393)
    at com.ibm.puremeap.resources.data.impl.PrincipalHelper.initializeSpecialPrincipals(PrincipalHelper.java:174)
    at com.ibm.puremeap.resources.data.impl.PureMeapData.<init>(PureMeapData.java:201)
    at com.ibm.puremeap.resources.data.impl.PureMeapData.fromDataSource(PureMeapData.java:102)
    at com.ibm.puremeap.resources.data.DataStoreFactory.getJPADBStore(DataStoreFactory.java:46)
    at com.ibm.puremeap.resources.data.DataStoreFactory.getDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:34)
    at com.ibm.puremeap.util.DataUtil.getData(DataUtil.java:453)
    at com.ibm.puremeap.listeners.AppCenterServletContextListener.checkAndUpgradeTo60(AppCenterServletContextListener.java:171)
    at com.ibm.puremeap.listeners.AppCenterServletContextListener.contextInitialized(AppCenterServletContextListener.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: This is AppCenter related error message. Are you using AppCenter also?Is your MFP runtime working fine?

Comment: Yes this is internal enterprise version. Wladmin/worklightconsole are running without errors, just stating no runtimes, even though I have install multiple times with config tool. I was trying to install 7.1 as a new package beside 6.1. I'm going to backup and try to install 7.1 in existing package of 6.1

Comment: May I won't install 7.1 in existing package.A problem occurred during the execution of the C:\Program Files\IBM\Worklight\WorklightServer\post-install.xml file. ERROR: The following error occurred while executing this line: C:\Program Files\IBM\Worklight\WorklightServer\post-install.xml:110: The following error occurred while executing this line: C:\Program Files\IBM\Worklight\WorklightServer\post-install.xml:322: Post-install actions failed.